# Сортировка массива коллекций в нужном порядке JS

Tags: javascript

Ребята всем привет, я нид хелп, как проще всего отсортировать в таком порядке как мне нужно? Например есть массив коллекций

```
const users = [
  { name: 'Mango', daysActive: 15 },
  { name: 'Poly', daysActive: 4 },
  { name: 'Ajax', daysActive: 27 },
  { name: 'Chelsey', daysActive: 2 },
];
```

Мне нужно сделать сортировку по имени например так:

```
const usersSort = [
 { name: 'Poly', daysActive: 4 },
 { name: 'Chelsey', daysActive: 2 },
 { name: 'Ajax', daysActive: 27 },
 { name: 'Mango', daysActive: 15 },
];
```

Я могу сделать find искать по каждому имени, пушить в новый массив и т.д. Может есть более простой вариант. По факту может быть 20 имен, можно как-то сделать универсальный сортировщик для любого количества данных? Кукую-то рекурсия например, передавать массив для сортировки в нужном порядке и на выходе будет отсортированный массив. Очень буду благодарен. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не понятно по какому критерию отсортировано то, что тебе нужно. если тебе нужна "сортировка по имени" то результат выглядит не так. (но если нужна то воспользуйся функцией Array.sort и localeCompare для сравнения)

Comment: Критерия сортировки нет. Есть данные, отсортировать по имени в том порядке как поставлено в задаче, сегодня по одному сортируем, завтра по другому. Например такой порядок ['Poly', 'Chelsey', 'Ajax', 'Mango'] , завтра другой порядок ['Chelsey', 'Poly','Mango' , 'Ajax', ] Как-то передавать массивом порядок сортировки

Comment: тогда тебе нужно иметь массив в котором имена отсортированы в нужном порядке, например, sortedNamed. вызываешь Array.sort и сортируешь по позиции имени в этом массиве, sortedNamed.indexOf(a.name) - sortedNamed.indexOf(b.name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам каждый раз нужно явно задавать порядок сортировки.

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Dummy', daysActive: 0 },
  { name: 'Mango', daysActive: 15 },
  { name: 'Poly', daysActive: 4 },
  { name: 'Ajax', daysActive: 27 },
  { name: 'Chelsey', daysActive: 2 },
];

function customSort(a, s) {
  return a.sort(function(x1, x2) {
    var i1 = s.indexOf(x1.name), 
        i2 = s.indexOf(x2.name);
    return i1 < 0 ? 1 : i2 < 0 ? -1 : i1 - i2;
  })
}

customSort(users, ['Poly', 'Chelsey', 'Ajax', 'Mango']);

console.log(users);
```

Comment: По поводу явно задавать это да. Но в ответе, получается исходный массив, без сортировки которой мне надо.

Comment: `console.log( usersSort === users ); // true` — Surprise) sort не только пересортирует исходный массив, но и возвращает его же) А `const` относится конкретно к этому имени-ссылке на массив. Ссылка и правда не меняется, а содержимое массива (как и других объектов) - вполне может. `s.indexOf(x.name) > s.indexOf(y.name)` — возвращает true / false, кстати, а sort ожидает положительные или отрицательные числа.

Comment: Знак больше на минус замените. Иначе массив не сортируется.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно заменил на - заработало:)

Comment: Можете еще подсказать, как сделать так, если в массиве для сортировки нет то чего ищу, оно становилось последним например var usersSort = customSort(users, ['Poly', 'Chelsey', 'Mango']); убрал 'Ajax' и оно должно быть последним в массиве. И можно ли вообще так сделать?

Comment: Тогда нужно проверять еще и на отсутствие индексов. Исправил.

Comment: { name: 'Dummy', daysActive: 0 } в начале после сортировки, а должен быть последним.

Comment: Мда, похоже Firefox и Chrome работают немного по-разному. Проверте работает ли у вас в Chrome теперь?

Comment: Все, заработало! Юхооо... Спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

Комент оставить не могу, не хватает репутации) Если надо чтобы имена не из массива попали в конец отсортированного массива, то надо добавить одну строчку к предложенному ответу:

```
function customSort(a, s) {
  return a.sort(function (x, y) {
    if (s.indexOf(x.name) === -1) return 1
    return s.indexOf(x.name) - s.indexOf(y.name);
  });
}
```

Comment: Немного не так, если взять const users = [
  { name: 'Dummy', daysActive: 0 },
  { name: 'Mango', daysActive: 15 },
  { name: 'Poly', daysActive: 4 },
  { name: 'Ajax', daysActive: 27 },
  { name: 'Chelsey', daysActive: 2 },
];
var usersSort = customSort(users, ['Poly', 'Chelsey', 'Ajax', 'Mango']);

console.log(usersSort);  то { name: 'Dummy', daysActive: 0 }, будет вначале, а должен быть в конце

Comment: в firefox будет при этом в конце, а в chrome вначале.